# How to correctly call a vba function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to vba, but I'm trying to create a function that dynamically finds the range of an entire sheet to be used in other macros for data cleaning.

Here is the function:

```
Public Function FindRange(Rw As Long, CL As Long)
Dim Rw As Long
Dim CL As Long

CL = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Column

Rw = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
End Function
```

Here is where I'm trying to call it:

```
Sub Range_Find_Method()


Call FindRange(Rw, CL)
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Cells(Rw, CL)).Select



End Sub
```

I keep getting a ByRef argument type mismatch.

Comment: Better to explain what you are trying to do, since it's not clear from your wrong code. Your function doesn't do anything, the variable with which are passing as parameters are set via `find` and then die when the function ends. If your function could return two items (it can't) then they would be of type `Range` but your `Cells(Rw, CL)` requires integers as parameters not Ranges.

Comment: See if you can modify this to suit (or better yet, just  use it): https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Comment: `Public Sub FindRange(ByRef Rw As Long, ByRef CL As Long)` but this is not the best approach to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call a function, you should assign it's return value to a variable in the calling sub/function. You should also give a function a return type eg

```
Public Function GetUsedRange() As Range
    Set GetUsedRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
End Function
```

Also, as the code above shows, can you not use

```
ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

To find the used range of cells?!  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-usedrange-property-excel

The function I've written is essentially redundant because you can just use

```
 Dim MyUsedRange As Range
 Set MyUsedRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

In which case, you don't even need to go as far as assigning the result to a variable, unless that used range changes during the course of your code running.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Public Function FindRange()
    Dim Rw As Long
    Dim CL As Long

    CL = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column

    Rw = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
    Dim arr(1 To 2) As Long
    arr(1) = CL
    arr(2) = Rw
    FindRange = arr
End Function

Sub MAIN()
    Dim coor() As Long
    coor = FindRange()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Cells(coor(2), coor(1))).Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Public Function FindRange(Rw As Long, CL As Long)
> Dim Rw As Long
> Dim CL As Long
> ```

That shouldn't even compile, `Rw` and `CL` local variables are *duplicate declarations* here:

[image: Compile error: duplicate declaration in current scope]

Remove them both, and your code should work as intended, i.e. assigning the `ByRef` **parameters** `Rw` and `CL`... which could both use a more descriptive name and an explicit `ByRef` modifier (it's implicit if unspecified).

Also, as others have hinted, functions are expected to *return a value*. You do that by specifying a *return type* in the function's signature...

```
Public Function FindRange(ByVal inRow As Long, ByVal inColumn As Long) As Range
```

...and then by assigning the function's identifier in the body of that function:

```
    Set FindRange = result ' where result is a Range object reference
```

Using `ByRef` parameters as return values works, but makes for a rather confusing API when the procedure is a `Function`. Making it a `Sub` procedure would remove the ambiguity about what the returned values might be, and again naming can help make the intent clearer:

```
Public Sub FindRange(ByRef outRow As Long, ByRef outColumn As Long)
```

The `Range.Find` method call you're making, is assuming a cell will be found - and will crash with run-time error 91 if invoked against an empty sheet. **Never** assume `Range.Find` will return a valid object reference - store its result in a `Range` object reference, and verify if it's `Nothing`:

```
Dim result As Range
Set result = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                    MatchCase:=False)
If Not result Is Nothing Then
    outRow = result.Row
    outColumn = result.Column
End If
```

As a bonus you avoid the need to make the same call twice. But then again, consider just returning the `result` range instead:

```
Set FindRange = result
```

Lastly, look [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1188513) for an actually reliable way to retrieve the last row/column on a worksheet. `UsedRange` can tell lies; that answer also lists various ways to do this, and why not to use them.

Comment: That single routine is not returning the true last row/last column if the only values in the worksheet were in B99 and Z2.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the range objects found.
2. Pass the parent worksheet in as an argument. Activesheet should never be used in a universal function and you are going to stop using it soon in any event.
3. Don't redim your arguments.
4. Since you only attributing new values byRef to the arguments and not returning a value from the function, this might as well be a sub procedure.
5. Dim the vars in your main. Use Option Explicit.

Here's a rewrite based on the notes above.

```
Public sub FindRange(ws as worksheet, byref Rw As Long, byref CL As Long)
    with ws
        CL = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                         After:=.cells(1), _
                         LookAt:=xlPart, _
                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                         MatchCase:=False).Column

        Rw = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                         After:=.cells(1), _
                         LookAt:=xlPart, _
                         LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                         MatchCase:=False).Row
    end with
End sub

Sub Range_Find_Method()

    Dim Rw As Long
    Dim CL As Long

    FindRange ActiveSheet, Rw, CL
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Cells(Rw, CL)).Select

End Sub
```

[image]